# Runtime error: `load of null pointer of type 'char'` when indexing an array

Tags: c, c-strings, trim, operator-precedence, pointer-to-pointer

I'm trying to write a trim function, but when I try to use it the compiler is giving me a runtime error or `load of null pointer of type 'char'` when I try to run this code:

```
// Trim trailing whitespace
int len = strlen(*str);
int trimmed = 0;

while (isspace(*str[len - 1])) {
    --len;
    trimmed = 1;
}
```

Here is my compiler command: `gcc  ./main.c ./json.c -g -m64 -Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=address,undefined,leak -I ./lib/include -L ./lib -o ./json`

This is the function that is causing the error:

```
void _JSON_Trim(char **str) {
  // Trim leading whitespace
  while (isspace(**str) || **str == '\0') {
    ++*str;
  }

  // Trim trailing whitespace
  int len = strlen(*str);
  int trimmed = 0;

  while (isspace(*str[len - 1])) {
    --len;
    trimmed = 1;
  }

  if (trimmed) {
    *str[len] = '\0';
  }
}
```

This code was semi-working until I added the double pointer symbol (`char **str` was `char *str`). However, `char *str` wasn't properly incrementing the pointer.

Note: the error specifically occurs in the line 11 where `while (isspace(*str[len - 1])) {` is called. I don't know where in the line it occurs as the compiler doesn't specify.

This is the string that the function is called on:

```
[
    "HI",
    "Bye"
]
```

Note: yes I know there's technically nothing to trim here, so the function wouldn't do anything, but it's there incase it does

Comment: `*str[len - 1]` is the same as `*(str[len - 1])` which doesn't seem right. Perhaps you meant `(*str)[len - 1]`?

Comment: Imagine `str` being allocated as `char[10]` initialized with `"         \0"` (ie nine spaces and a terminating `\0`) Then your code goes beyond the end of the allocated memory.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Yes, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postfix subscript operator has a higher priority than the unary dereferncing operator. This line

```
while (isspace(*str[len - 1])) {
```

is equivalent to

```
while (isspace(*( str[len - 1] ))) {
```

while you need to write

```
while (isspace( ( *str )[len - 1])) {
```

And it ie even better to write

```
while (isspace( ( unsigned char )( *str )[len - 1])) {
```

Pay attention to that the variable `len` shall have type `size_t` instead of the type `int`

```
int len = strlen(*str);.
```

`size_t` is the return type of the function `strlen`.

Comment: It might be worth suggesting that the function should return the new start to the string, which means it could revert to taking a `char *`argument.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In my opinion the function should move the string to the left overriding leading spaces.